# bitwise most significant set bit

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I want to find the most significant bit that is set to `1`. I have tried every possible way from `&` to ORing all of the bits from `1` to `31` and it doesn't work.

Like if `1000000` I would like to have `7`.

Comment: What did you try in detail? What was the result?

Comment: I did all of the  count += 1&(~x >> 1-31); and it gave me different numbers than what I expected I want the most significant bit that is 1 and thats it

Comment: How should negative numbers be treated?

Comment: Doesn't matter I need the most significant bit that is 1 thats all. so even if I have -2 I still need the most significant bit with the 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you insist on directly using bitwise operators, you can try something like this:

```
private int mostSignificantBit(int myInt){
  int mask = 1 << 31;
  for(int bitIndex = 31; bitIndex >= 0; bitIndex--){
    if((myInt & mask) != 0){
      return bitIndex;
    }
    mask >>>= 1;
  }
  return -1;
}
```

We initialize the mask to `1 << 31` because that represents a 1 followed by 31 0's.  We use that value to test if index 31 (the 32nd spot) is a 1.  When we `and` this value with `myInt`, we get a 0 unless the corresponding bit is set in `myInt`.  If this is the case, we return that `bitIndex`.  If not, then we shift the mask to the right by 1 and try again.  We repeat until we run out of places to shift, in which case it means none of the bits were set (maybe you want to throw an exception here instead of returning -1).

Note that this will return the value `0` for `1` and `6` for `64` (`1000000` in binary).  You can adjust that if you prefer.  Note also that I used the unsigned right operator rather than the signed right shift.  This is because the intent here is to deal with raw bits rather than their signed interpretation, but it doesn't matter in this instance since all negative values will terminate in the first iteration of the loop before shifting occurs.

Comment: Actually the use of the unsigned right shift operator is important. If `myInt` is _not_ negative, then you'll need to shift `mask` and it starts off as a negative value.

Comment: You're correct that `mask` will always have a leading 1 that doesn't belong if the signed right shift is used (since `mask` starts out as negative).  However, this doesn't affect results of my implementation because when `myInt` is not negative, that superfluous 1-bit is always being `and`ed with a 0 (i.e. the sign bit of `myInt`, which we just said was positive).

Comment: Good point! I hadn't worked through the consequences of having leading 1s in `mask`, which (as you point out) are precisely nothing.

Answer (score 20):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#numberOfLeadingZeros%28int%29
You want something like `32 - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(value)`.

Answer (score 15):

The slickest implementation I've come across - three iterations and a table lookup.

```
unsigned int msb32(unsigned int x)
{
    static const unsigned int bval[] =
    { 0,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4 };

    unsigned int base = 0;
    if (x & 0xFFFF0000) { base += 32/2; x >>= 32/2; }
    if (x & 0x0000FF00) { base += 32/4; x >>= 32/4; }
    if (x & 0x000000F0) { base += 32/8; x >>= 32/8; }
    return base + bval[x];
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Though there is an answer accepted, I have another ways to share which I think is easier.

If you want to use bitwise operations, here is the way.  Basically, I am right-shifting the integer until it become zero. No mask is required.

```
private static int mostSignificantBit(int myInt){
    int i = 0;
    while (myInt != 0) {
        ++i;
        myInt >>>= 1;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Another way is calculate it mathematically:

```
private static int mostSignificantBit(int myInt){
    if (myInt == 0) return 0;    // special handling for 0
    if (myInt < 0) return 32;    // special handling for -ve

    return (int)(Math.log(myInt)/Math.log(2)) +1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Successive approximation will minimize the iterations to five loops:

```
unsigned int mostSignificantBit(uint32_t val) {
  unsigned int bit = 0;

  /* 4 = log(sizeof(val) * 8) / log(2) - 1 */
  for(int r = 4; r >= 0 ; --r) {
    unsigned shift = 1 << r; /* 2^r */
    uint32_t sval = val >> shift;
    if (sval) {
        bit += shift;
        val = sval;
    }
  }
  return bit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the most efficient, perhaps, but this should work::

```
public int firstBit(int i) {
    return i < 0 ? 31 : i == 0 ? 0 : Integer.toString(i, 2).length();
}
```

Comment: No... just no. Yes it works, but ouch is it wasteful.

Answer (score -1):

Just to add another approach

```
public static int mostSignificantBit(int b) {
    for (int i = 1 << 30, j = 0; i > 0; i /= 2, j++) {
           if ((b & i) > 0) {
            return 31-j;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: You probably want to input an `int` rather than a `byte`.

Comment: I don't think your starting point is correct.  This code gives the same answer for `Integer.MAX_VALUE` as it does for negative numbers.

Answer (score -1):

Just use numberOfTrailingZeros(value) method of Long or Integer class.

Answer (score -1):

For Little Endian format:

```
((yourByte & yourBitMask) >> msbIndex) && 0x01
```

Answer (score -3):

```
if( value | 0x40 ) return 7;
else if( value | 0x20 ) return 6;
else if( value | 0x10 ) return 5;
else if( value | 0x8 ) return 4;
else if( value | 0x4 ) return 3;
else if( value | 0x2 ) return 2;
else if( value | 0x1 ) return 1;
```

Comment: What happened to returning 8 through 31?