# Masking Highest Set Bit in R?

Tags: r, bit-manipulation

I'm working in R.  I need to find a fast function that will mask the highest set bit of an integer.  For example:

```
# 6 binary is 110, this should turn into 010 which is 2
function_mask(6) = 2

# 8 in binary is 1000, this should turn into 0000
function_mask(8) = 0
```

This is equivalent to subtracting the closest lower power of two.  I will be happy if I can find a fast function that will simply find the closest lower power of two.  For example:

```
# 6 in binary is 110, the MSB is 100
function_power_two(6) = 4
function_mask(6) = 6 - function_power_two(6) = 2

# 8 in binary is 1000, the MSB is 1000 which is 8 in base 10
function_power_two(8) = 8
function_mask(8) = 8 - function_power_two(8) = 0
```

I have found bitwise operations in R: for example, bitwShiftL and bitwShiftR.  However, I do not know how to implement a solution in R.

I have seen solutions in other languages: [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9117793/bitwise-most-significant-set-bit), [C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21413565/create-a-mask-that-marks-the-most-significant-set-bit-using-only-bitwise-operat), and [C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671815/what-is-the-fastest-most-efficient-way-to-find-the-highest-set-bit-msb-in-an-i).  However, I do not know how to implement these solutions in R.

There are solutions in C++ using Rcpp, however Rcpp does not support integers larger than 32-bit.  I need larger integers than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function is even faster (4x) than [the answer I posted earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38879659/2761575).

```
pow2 <- c(0,1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024)
function_mask <- function(x) x - pow2[findInterval(x, pow2)]
```

You can make the pow2 vector as long as needed, to cope with larger integers

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this :

```
function_mask <- function(x) {
    bits = intToBits(x)                 # Convert integer to binary vector
    ii = tail(which(bits > 0), n=1)     # Identify most significant bit
    bits[ii] = as.raw(0)                # Mask the most significant bit
    out = packBits(bits,type='integer') # Convert binary back to integer
    return(out)
}
```

Testing :

```
function_mask(6) = 2
function_mask(8) = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's fast, but here's another possibility:

```
maskHighBit <- function(x){strtoi(sub("^1", "", R.utils::intToBin(x)), base=2)}
```

Answer (score 0):

For an R solution:

```
function_mask <- function(x) {
  xb <-intToBits(x)
  highestbit <- length(xb) - match("01", rev(xb)) 
  x-2L^highestbit
}
```

Comparing speeds to the other answers, we see this one is fastest, so far.

```
function_mask1 <- function(x) {
  bits = intToBits(x)                 # Convert integer to binary vector
  ii = tail(which(bits > 0), n=1)     # Identify most significant bit
  bits[ii] = as.raw(0)                # Mask the most significant bit
  out = packBits(bits,type='integer') # Convert binary back to integer
  return(out)
}

maskHighBit <- function(x){
  strtoi(gsub("^1", "", R.utils::intToBin(as.integer(x))), base=2)}

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(function_mask(112L), function_mask1(112L), maskHighBit(112L), times=1000)
#Unit: microseconds
#expr     min      lq      mean  median      uq      max neval cld
#function_mask(112L)  17.961  20.014  23.65080  23.092  24.632   57.475  1000 a  
#function_mask1(112L)  39.514  44.132  49.79744  47.724  49.777  107.765  1000  b 
#maskHighBit(112L) 108.791 114.435 127.53792 118.540 133.422 2054.189  1000   c
```