# The most EFFIECIENT algorithm to find how many times a number can be divided by 2 before it reaches 1 [Note: if possible in O(1) time]

Tags: algorithm, numbers

I tried using log but it is consuming more time than the iterative version for finding the answer.
The number is integer.

```
Using log:-
int ans = (log(x)/log(2));

Iterative version:-
int temp;
while(x)
{
    temp = temp/2;
    count++;
}
count--;
```

Comment: Real life efficient (see existing answers) or asymptotically efficient (see other existing answers)?

Comment: Is your number size and type known (32-bit/64-bit integer, 32-bit float, ...) ? I can only guess it's an integer since it "reaches 1" when successively dividing it by 2.

Comment: @Nelxiost floats also reach zero eventually

Comment: @harold They don't necessarily reach one, though.

Comment: @Nelxiost no but the code doesn't test for that anyway

Comment: @harold From what is shown, the code doesn't test for anything. The question implies that a number eventually reaches 1 when successively divided by 2. A floating-point number doesn't work that way. An integer does. What's your point ?

Comment: @Nelxiost it doesn't rely on reaching 1 at all, though it would anyway since this is definitely the integer version so the only way to get 0 is by getting to 1 first. It relies on reaching 0, which also works for floats, but then this ends up being wrong anyway so it cannot be the float version.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9117793/bitwise-most-significant-set-bit

Comment: @Nelxiost If number is integer it will reach 1 Sorry for not telling you the datatype.  I have edited it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Basic Integer datatype**

   for integers on **x86** architecture there is a single `O(1)` instruction for this:

   - [BSR bit scan reverse](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_20.html)

   that returns position of MSB set bit. So you do not need to do the iterative `O(log(n))` dividing, shifting or bin-search. To make sure the sign (2'os complement) does not mess this up for negative numbers use `abs` value for this.
2. **bigints**

   For these you need to check the MSW non zero WORD. and use **#1** on it. This is `O(log(n))`. Where `n` is the number you are testing.
3. **floating point**

   These are usually very simple `O(1)` as you just extract exponent which tells you the position of MSB set bit directly.

   Also `log2` is directly implemented by **FPU HW** for basic floating datatypes on most architectures but they will not return integer style result ...